# sharing variables among methods of same class in android

Tags: java, android

My Problem is I can't use the food1(Object of Food class which Stores the value of food which is selected) object's values in onclickfoodimage() function
which I have initialized in onCreate() *(onClickFoodImage is the method which is called when image is clicked)*

**FoodActivity Class**

```
public class FoodActivity extends Activity {
public static  final String EXTRA_MESSAGE2="message";
Food food1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Intent intent=getIntent();
int Foodno=intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
food1=Food.food[Foodno];
ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
image.setImageResource(food1.getFoodImageId());

}
public final void onclickfoodimage()
{
TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
textview.setText(food1.getFoodName());
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
textView.setText(food1.getFoodDescription());
}
}
```

**Food Class containing the food Data of which food1 is object**

```
public class Food {
String foodName,foodDescription;
int foodImageId;
static Food food[]={new Food("Dosa","A South Indian Dish",R.drawable.dosa),new Food("Paneer","A Famous And Delicious Dish made from Paneer",R.drawable.paneer)};
Food(String name,String description,int id)
{
    this.foodName=name;
    this.foodDescription=description;
    foodImageId=id;
}
String getFoodName()
{
    return foodName;
}
String getFoodDescription()
{
    return foodDescription;
}
int getFoodImageId()
{
    return foodImageId;
}
public String toString()
{
    return foodName;
}

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you put some logcat error messages here so that I can understand your problem ?

Comment: The problem is when I click on the image the app stops working....and return back to the Food Activity class...is it because onClickfoodimage's food1 is different from  onCreate's food1 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems **onclickfoodimage()** is not being called when you click on ImageView , Here I have develop a complete program for you , I have not tested this , hope this will work for you .

**MainActivity.java** , which starts FoodActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static  final String EXTRA_MESSAGE2="message";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this , FoodActivity.class).putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2,1);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

FoodActivity.java :

```
    public class FoodActivity extends Activity {
    public static  final String EXTRA_MESSAGE2="message";
    Food food1;
    static ArrayList<Food> foodArray = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        foodArray.add(new Food("Dosa","A South Indian Dish",R.drawable.dosa)) ;
        foodArray.add(new Food("Paneer","A Famous And Delicious Dish made from Paneer",R.drawable.paneer)) ;

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        int Foodno=intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
        food1=foodArray.get(Foodno);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        image.setImageResource(food1.getFoodImageId());

    }
    public final void onclickfoodimage(View v)
    {
        TextView textview4 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textview4.setText(food1.getFoodName());

        TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView5.setText(food1.getFoodDescription());
    }
}
```

Food.java :

```
    public class Food {
    String foodName,foodDescription;
    int foodImageId;

    Food(String name,String description,int id)
    {
        this.foodName=name;
        this.foodDescription=description;
        foodImageId=id;
    }
    String getFoodName()
    {
        return foodName;
    }
    String getFoodDescription()
    {
        return foodDescription;
    }
    int getFoodImageId()
    {
        return foodImageId;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return foodName;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.shishupalshakya.accessstringvariable.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="onclickfoodimage"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note : Don't forgot to register FoodActivity.java in the AndroidManifest.xml file .

Simply replace your code with above code .

Comment: Got the problem...havn't passed View view in onclickfoodimage()....but why i have to pass View's object in the function??